# Add a listview programmatically to all lists in Sharepoint 2013 C#

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, view

I need to create a view for all the lists. The view has to show the fields that are mandatory (is different in every list).

It all goes wrong when the second list is retrieved. The first for-each gives the following error message:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

I really don't know why I get this bug.

```
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPListCollection myLists = myWeb.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
        StringCollection viewFields = new StringCollection();
        String viewName = "Mandatory fields view";
        String query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified'/></OrderBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID Type='Integer' /></Value></Eq></Where>";

        foreach (SPList list in myLists)
        {
         foreach (SPField field in list.Fields)
            {

                if (field.Required)
                {
                    viewFields.Add(field.ToString());
                }

            }
            list.Views.Add(viewName, viewFields, query, Int32.MaxValue, true, false);
            viewFields.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could just use a for loop instead of a foreach:

```
for(int i = 0; i< myLists.Count; i++){
  SPList list = myLists[i];
  //etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `foreach (SPList list in myLists)` to `foreach (SPList list in myLists.ToList())`. This will copy the values of myLists to a separate list that can not be modified during each foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I used the for loop instead of foreach.